# Audio file is not working via FTP upload programatically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am uploading an .mp3 file via FTP code using C#, the file is uploaded successfully on server but when i bind to a simple audio control or directly view in browser it does not work as expected, whereas when i upload manually on the server it works perfectly.

Code:

```
        var inputStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[inputStream.Length];
        inputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
```

Note: When i view the file in Firefox it shows MIME type is not supported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the file as a string then using UTF8 encoding to turn it into bytes. If you do that, and the file contains any binary sequence that doesn't code to a valid UTF8 value, parts of the data stream will simply get discarded.

Instead, read it directly as bytes. Don't bother with the StreamReader.  Call  the [Read() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) on the underlying stream. Example:

```
var inputStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[inputStream.Length];
inputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileStream.Length);
```

Comment: Works Perfect! Big Thanks John!